# Force step() to keep a certain valuable

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm using `step()` to find a model to adjust a score based on other variables. My full model is thus :

```
mod<-lm(Adjusted.score ~ original.score + X1 + X2 + X3 + ... + X10)
```

It's logical that I need to keep the variable `original.score` in the final model but `step()` always omits it. Is there a way to force `step()` to keep the variable `original.score` and find the best combinations of the other variables to accompany it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for this (from `?step`):

```
The set of models searched is determined by the ‘scope’ argument.
The right-hand-side of its ‘lower’ component is always included in
the model, and right-hand-side of the model is included in the
‘upper’ component.  If ‘scope’ is a single formula, it specifies
the ‘upper’ component, and the ‘lower’ model is empty.  If ‘scope’
is missing, the initial model is used as the ‘upper’ model.

Models specified by ‘scope’ can be templates to update ‘object’ as
used by ‘update.formula’.  So using ‘.’ in a ‘scope’ formula means
‘what is already there’, with ‘.^2’ indicating all interactions of
existing terms.
```

Responding to your comment: I haven't done this sort of thing before but a small example included below seems to do what you are asking for:

```
x = setNames(lapply(1:5, function (x) runif(100)), letters[1:5])
step(lmObj, scope=list(lower=as.formula(a ~ b), upper=as.formula(a ~ .)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did `step(mod, list(Adjusted.score ~ original.score, mod))` but this does not keep original.score in the best model. I am confused as to the 'scope' syntax.

Comment: OK, so I found the solution, this modified code works ands forces it to keep the variable `original.score`: `step(mod, scope=list(lower=Adjusted.score ~ original.score, upper=mod))`